# Add view controller before tabbar controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm new to objective-c and ios programming. I am building a tabbar application. But before the tabbar view controller loads. I want to load a "Login screen".

-I was able to do this HALFWAY.

I created a new tabbar application. 
I added a new view controller and made it the "Initial" view controller, created a new objective-c class and associated it to the new view controller.

Now how would I load the tabbar view controller after checking the users username/password?

Comment: Are you using storyboard or do you do that programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

The best/easiest way to do this would probably be not to to have the `UITabBarController` at the start.

Have your `LoginViewController` be the `rootViewController` of your `window` until the user logs in. Then change it to be the `UITabBarController` (which does not include the login view). You would do this in your `AppDelegate.m` file.

Comment: Dima, Thanks for the quick reply. So i did the following: imported my LoginViewController in AppDelegate.h, created a new property. Then in my AppDelegate.m under didFinishLaunchingWithOptions; I added: self.window.rootViewController = self.loginController. When I run it, the screen comes up black and I get a "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

Answer (score 3):

I would leave the tab bar controller as your root view controller. In `viewDidAppear`, check whether your user is logged in, and if not, present the login view controller modally with no animation.

```
UIViewController *loginVC = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"storyboard" instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
[self presentViewController:loginVC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

When the user successfully logs in, you can dismiss the login VC. It will slide down, revealing your tabbed layout.

If you need a more complex hierarchy for login (maybe you need to push on a registration view, or a 'you failed to login' view, etc.), you can just embed the login view controller in a nav controller and present that instead.

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on the 3rd para? Or maybe create a tutorial?:) Thanks.